# Using Netbeans on Mac, Netbeans cannot find .txt file

Tags: java, ios, file, netbeans, io

I'm trying to write a program that retrieves a pre-made .txt file.

The .txt file is called "Program3.txt" and is placed in
/users/(me)/NetBeansProjects/Assn3Prog3/src/assn3prog3/Program3.txt

**When i prompt the user:**

```
filename = keyboard.nextLine();        
file1 = new File(filename); 
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file1);
```

**the following error is returned:**

> Program3.txt Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   Program3.txt (No such file or directory)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:611)    at
>   assn3prog3.Assn3Prog3.main(Assn3Prog3.java:31)
>   /Users/conormontgomery/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)

Disclaimers:

"`import.java.io;`" & "`public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException`"

are in the program

**I'm using the book "Starting out with JAVA: From controls through objects" for base knowledge, if that helps :)**

Comment: This has nothing to do with NetBeans or MacOS, but you misunderstand of how putting `Program3.txt` in the `src` does.  Instead of using `File`, you need to use `Class#getResouce` (or `Class#getResourceAsStream`) to get the resource from inside the application context.

Comment: Another option is to just input the full absolute path of the file.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're saying I can't put the .txt file in the src folder?

Comment: I apologize for my naivity in advance : |

Comment: @pvg how would I go about doing that

Comment: @Conor Yes, you can, but it changes the way you can access it. You should never generate a path which has `src` in it.  In your case, the file will become bundled within the program context (ie the Jar) and you will only be able to access via the `Class#getResource/AsStream` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put files into the src/ directory, they get built inside the program. I believe you intended for the text file to be outside the program so that it can load from file.

Programs have a "working directory" which is where the program is run and looks for related files. When using an IDE, the working directory is never in the src/ folder, since it doesn't make since to be reading your own source code (in most cases). To find out the working directory, try:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

This will print the working directory of your program. You'll need to move the text file there instead of in the src/ folder.

Comment: Thanks to you and @MadProgrammer

Comment: So how would I get NetBeans to find/open the file on my desktop?

Comment: @Conor Operating system specific, for Mac I believe you can make the file path "~/Desktop/Program3.txt". That's an absolute path (relative path is when you describe a file's location relative to the current one). When you provide an absolute path, the program will look in that exact position.